# Percentage change per user_id month by month

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, which structure looks like that:

[image: df1]

And in pandas I would like to have percentage change by month per every user, so I would like to receive result like below:

[image: df2]

I was trying to get this result by doing pivot:

```py
pivot_target1 = pd.pivot_table(target_group1, values=['volume_usd'], index=['user_id', 'date'],
                    aggfunc=pct_change())
```

I added here aggfunc as pct_change as an example to show my logic but it doesn't work. Is there any function in pivot which I can use to have percentage change by month? Or maybe totally different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"user_id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], "volume": [10000, 15000, 12000, 5000, 7000]}
)
```

Groupby (see Pandas documentation):

```
df["pct_change"] = df.groupby("user_id")["volume"].pct_change()
```

Output:

```
   user_id  volume  pct_change
0        1   10000         NaN
1        1   15000         0.5
2        1   12000        -0.2
3        2    5000         NaN
4        2    7000         0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking the solution, just use `groupby` with `pct_change`. There is no need for a pivot table.

```
df.assign(pct_change=df.groupby("user_id")["volume_usd"].pct_change() * 100)

   user_id       date  volume_usd  pct_change
0        1  2/28/2021       10000         NaN
1        1  3/31/2021       15000        50.0
2        1  4/30/2021       12000       -20.0
3        2  2/28/2021        5000         NaN
4        2  3/31/2021        7000        40.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `groupby` with `pct_change`:

```
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby('user_id')['volume_usd'].pct_change().mul(100).round()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   user_id       date  volume_usd  pct_change
0        1  2/28/2021       10000         NaN
1        1  3/31/2021       15000        50.0
2        1  4/30/2021       12000       -20.0
3        2  2/28/2021        5000         NaN
4        2  3/31/2021        7000        40.0
```